# Custom View redraws only once, then onDraw is called but screen is not updated

Tags: android, view

I have an View subclass and it call onDraw but the screen is not updated at once.

Note that, when I set my app to compatibility `SDK (Target SDK Api Level 8)` it works. Target `SDK 14` it is never gets updated.

The onDraw is called, but it's like drawing to a sink.

What could be wrong?

EDIT: I saw that it's actually an GLES20Recording canvas for drawing, but this doesn't explain why it doesn't redraw. When I set the view to software rendering mode, it draws.

Comment: Could you paste only the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, Views have to be software accelerated.

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Stupid, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

To force a view to draw, to call [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) or [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29).  This can be done on any view subclass.

Answer (score 0):

With API 14 your app is hardware accelerated. Are you sure you are
calling invalidate() on the View that contains this drawPath code?

Thanks

Comment: Also check this post :: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HgGVSbSghpk